# What is the meaning of this error mean when starting RStudio?

Tags: python, r, rstudio, startup

When RStudio starts the following error appears in the console:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -c "import sys; print(sys.platform)"'
Calls: do.call -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> vapply -> FUN
Execution halted
```

I am not using Python but have it installed. The error does not appear to have consequences when using R.
Any explanations, should I worry about it?
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that either you have something in your `~/.Rprofile` script, or you're running in the RStudio IDE and it is inferring something about your environment and failing when acting on that assumption.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will look into '~./Rprofile'. Thanks.